# Is there a way to pass the Windows Authentication session between my ASP.Net MVC 5 apps?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

I have multiple ASP.NET MVC 5 based app running in the same IIS server with Different Web Pools.

All my apps use Windows Authentication to log the user in. My issue is that the user must get authenticated for each app before he/she can use it.

I am looking into creating new app that will manage the authentication and will pass the windows authenticated session to the rest of the apps. So in my existing apps, I would redirect to the new app aka authenticationBroker app if there is no session available. My authenticationBroker will prompt the user to provider the Windows Credintials, once authenticated the user is redirected back to th referrer app along with the authenticated session so I can pass the same session to other integrated services if needed.

I can design my authenticationBroker to create a token after the user is authenticated and store it in a database somewhere. Then I can use that token to retrieve the user create a user Identity. However, this will not share my IIS authenticated session with the apps, instead it will share a token.

How can I create an authentication broker that will pass and manages my actual Windows Authentication session to all of my apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly share the session state.
This would require you to setup a persistent shared facility to distribute the session across your processes (e.g. see here how to do this with Redis: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1040453/ASP-NET-Session-State-Management-with-Redis-Local)

Whether you can share the authentication will depend on if you use NTLM or Basic authentication. I am not confident whether this could be achieved with NTLM. I am pretty confident this can NOT be achieved with Kerberos as the ticket would be issued to the user + process (although you may have some luck running all app pools as the same user...)

Further, if the app is available on internet (as opposed to intranet), i would not recommend using none of the windows auth options, and instead opt for a Windows auth-to-cookie or Windows auth-to-token replacement (it doesn't have to be done as an STS/broker that you described, you can also run 3 separate login pages, so long as the cookie/token issued is recognized by all 3 apps; of course that sounds like a weird approach but reasons for doing that may include, among others, the need to brand the login pages differently at different times or legacy codebases).